# How do I get code to repeat its inputs

Tags: python, input, repeat

Basically, I want this code to keep asking me for the inputs until I close the page. Just started learning Python today so sorry if this is written really bad. Written in Python 3.5, and saves the passwords you enter into it in a text document so you can remember them.

```
website = input("Enter what website the password is for     ")
username = input("Enter your username     ")
password = input("Enter your password     ")  
textfile = open("usernames.txt", "a")
textfile.write(website+"         ")
textfile.write(username+"         ")
textfile.write(password+"\n")
textfile.close()
```

Comment: check out [while loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop)

Comment: You should keep learning. You will get to loops very soon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is,

```
while True:
    <Your Code.....>
```

Infinite loop.